# Firebase/nodeJS : Add new elements without disturbing the records

Tags: node.js, firebase

In this code :

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
  username: name,
  email: email,
  profile_picture : imageUrl
},
```

The existing elements of `userID` is deleted when executed. How to dd new elements without disturbing the existing array?

Answer (score 0):

If we refer to the documentation, the set method is used to "Write or replace data to a defined path". To add new elements without replacing, you can use the "update" or "push" method. Please refer the documentation. I've added the link below.

[Saving Data | Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)